# Select Statement using prepared and fetching data into array

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I'm trying to implement a basic login functionality on my website. I'm using the following code to fetch data from database and see if the username and password is correct or not:

```
$STH = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE uid = '$uid'");
$STH->bindParam(':uid', $uid);
$STH->bindParam(':pass', $pass);

$uid = $_POST['uid'];
$pass = $_POST['pass'];

if($STH->execute()) {

        if($row = $STH->fetch()) {
            if ($row['pass'] == $pass) {
                echo "Logged in Successfully <br>";
                } else {
                    echo "Username or Password Incorrect<br>";
                }

            } else {
                    echo "<script>alert('Incorrect Username');</script>";
            }
        }
}
```

However, I keep getting the error `Incorrect Username` even though it is in the database. This means that there is something wrong with how I'm fetching the data after executing the query but I can't understand what exactly.

Comment: You're using prepared statements wrong way. Let me recommend you a [PDO tutorial](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo) I wrote.

Comment: `WHERE uid = '$uid'` < that's where you've gone wrong and not binding anything in your query.

Comment: Read the manual, it's much better http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements

Comment: Oh i got it! @Fred-ii- thanks for spotting that error.

Comment: @Ankush welcome. this is the syntax you need `$STH = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE uid = :uid AND password = :pass");` and used "password", you need to use the one you're using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the prepared statements incorrectly. I wasn't really binding anything in the query. The correct implementation would have been:

```
$STH = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE uid = :uid");
```